# Create pdf for signature list using Laravel and dompdf

Tags: laravel, dompdf, laravel-8

I'm stuck on a problem that I thought should be straightforward, but dompdf refuses to make my pdf as I want it. I want a pdf that my end user should print out containing a list with users with their names and a line where they should sign. Something like this:

[image: Picture showing how I want it to look]

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
<style>
    .lineContainer div {height: 30px;} 
    .nounderscore {border-bottom: 0px;float:left;}
    .underscore {border-bottom: 1px solid #000; overflow: hidden;}
</style>

@foreach($users as $user)
    <div class="lineContainer">
        <div class="nounderscore">{{$user->name}}</div>
        <div class="underscore"></div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This works fine when rendered as html, but when I use it for a pdf file it ends up with my underline starting from the far left end of the page, so also the names are underlined. Any ideas how to do this in a way that works with dompdf?

Comment: Why don't you try table tag to make a list?

Comment: I tried doing a table instead but it gets even worse, actually all names except for the first ended up in the top left corner of the pdf. It's obviously very hard getting anything at all with a decent layout on a pdf file :-(

Comment: try using li I guess it should solve it for you in pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
li{
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  list-style: none;
}
.line{
  padding-right: 15em;
  margin: 0 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

</style>
<ul>
@foreach($users as $user)
    <li>{{$user->name}}<span class="line"></span></li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer preview for static data:
https://jsfiddle.net/wz1vpsnx/